# What is the font of this J?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, math-fonts

[image]

What is the font of this J here  ?

Comment: The code is either `\mathcal` or `\mathscr` depends on the used font

Comment: At least in amsmath package, it is not \mathcal{J} and \mathscr{J}. I have tried it.

Comment: if you have the pdf of the original use menu of your pdf viewer or the pdffonts tool to list the fonts

Comment: @thone Sorry, I already mentioned that its depends on the used font

Comment: whatfontis (see [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/277964)) show several suitable fonts, e.g., News Platin Italic, OPTIPlanet-Italic, Aldine 721 Italic, Janson Text Italic, Hoefler Text Italic, …, Libertinus Serif Italic, …

Comment: @thone - It's not a script-J. Rahter, it's a script-F letter.